# XPath : How to get text between 2 html tags with same level?

Tags: html, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and I'm working with [scrapy](/questions/tagged/scrapy) to get text from different html pages that are generated.
I get the {id} of a header tag from the user (`<h1|2|.. id="title-{id}">text</h1|2|3..>`). I need to get text from all html tags between this header and the next header of same level. So if the header is h1 I need to get all text of all tags until next h1 header.
All headers ids have same pattern "title-{id}" where {id} is generated.
To make it more clear here is an example :

```
<html>
    <body>
        ...
        <h2 id="tittle-id1">id1</h2>
        bunch of tags containing text I want to get
        <h2 id="tittle-id2">id2</h2>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE : I don't know what header it might be. It could be any of the html header tags from `<h1>` to `<h6>`**

---

**UPDATE :**
While trying few things around I noticed that I'm not sure if the next header is of same level or even exists. Since the headers are used as titles and sub-titles. The given id may be of last sub-title hence I'll have a header of higher level after or even be the last of the page. So basicaly I only have the id of the header and I need to get all text of the "paragraph".

---

**Work Around :** 
I found a kindof workaround solution : 
I do it in 3 steps :
First, I use `//*[@id='title-{id}]` which allows me to get the full line with the tag so now I know which tag header it is.
Second, I use `//*[id='title-{id}]/following-sibling::*` this allows to look for next header of same or higher level {myHeader}.
Last, I use `//*[id='title-{id}]/following-sibling::*` and `//{myHeader}//preceding-sibling::*` to get what's between or go 'till the end of page if no header found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what worked for me :**  
For this keep in mind that I'm using [scrapy](/questions/tagged/scrapy) with [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) :

```
name_query = u"//*[name()=name(//*[@id='"+id+"'])]"
all = response.xpath(name_query)
for selector in all.getall():
     if self.id in selector:
          position = all.getall().index(selector)
balise = "h" + all.getall()[position].split("<h")[1][0]
title = all.getall()[position].split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
query = u"//*[preceding-sibling::"+balise+"[1] ='"+title+"' and following-sibling::"+balise+"]"
self.log('query = '+query)
results = response.xpath(query)
results.pop(len(results)-1)
with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    for text in results.css("::text").getall():
        f.write(text.encode('utf-8')+"\n")
```

This should work in general I tested it against multiple headers wih different levels it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the xpath to get all the elements between h2 tags.

```
//h2/following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=1]
```

Here is the sample html I used to simulate the scenario. (update the id to check different options shown in the below).

> //*[@id='tittle-id1' ]/following::*[count(following-sibling::*[name()=name(preceding-sibling::*[@id='tittle-id1'])])=1]

```html
<html><head></head><body>
 
        ...
        <h2 id="tittle-id1">id1</h2>
    <h3 id="tittle-id3"> h3 tag</h3>
    <h4 id="tittle-id4"> h4 tag</h4>
    <h3 id="tittle-id5"> 2nd h3  tag</h3>
        bunch of tags containing text I want to get
     <h5 id="tittle-id6"> h5 tag </h5>
        <h2 id="tittle-id2">id2</h2>
  <h4 id="tittle-id7"> 2nd h4 tag</h4>
        ...
    
 
</body></html>
```

output if User input: {id1}
[image]

output if user input: {id4}
[image]

output if user input: {id3}
[image]

**Note: This xpath is designed to suite the original post scenario.**

Comment: This would work if I knew what would be the header html tag (`<h2>` in the example). But if you read carefully I only have the id. I don't know what header tag it is. It could be any of 'em from `<h1>` to `<h6>`

Comment: Got you, let me update my answer which will get all element between two tags based on the id.

Comment: your solution seems to imply that I know that `n`, which I don't. But I think it's my fault for not being more precise. when I said id1 or id2 it was just an example the actual id is a generated string from the actual title.

Comment: `n` in there is not the number from `id`. It's the nth item, you should use a loop to get all the headers info and as part of loop you can update the `n` value.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. Check my latest update you may find the new work around a good solution.In which case I will post as solution and check it for others to use

Comment: @supputuri Shouldn't the first xpath be `//h2/following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)<2]` so that you include the following siblings of the last `h2` ?

Comment: @CJ7 OP does not know the tag `h?` so you can't hard code that in the xpath.

Comment: @Deyesta Can you please check with this xpath `//*[@id='tittle-id1' ]/following::*[count(following-sibling::*[name()=name(preceding-sibling::*[@id='tittle-id1'])])=1]` and let me know. So that I can update this in the answer. This will bring all the elements between two `h?` tags based on the first h? tag id provided by user.

Comment: @supputuri Ok, but my difference is doing `<2` instead of `=1`

Comment: @CJ7 if  it's `<2` then it will find all the following element that are after the next h2 tag. Check your xpath with the html that I added in the answer. As per the OP all those h? are siblings that's where the complexity  and we are not sure the order of the tags.

Comment: @supputuri your xpath did give me an expected paragraph the only problem is that it gave an other one not the one labeled by the id I gave

Comment: Can you ping me the xpath that you used?

Comment: I used this xpath :`//*[@id='tittle-id1' ]/following::*[count(following-sibling::*[name()=name(preceding-sibling::*[@id='tittle-id1'])])=1]`. It looks like this xpath gives exactly a "paragraph" except that it is for `title-id?`. I'm not in liberty to share a real life example and that's could be the reason why you can't achieve the right answer.

Comment: Tried your xpath and on the sample page that I uploaded in the answer and it's working as expected. Is it possible to mock the data and share the exact structure?

Answer (score 1):

Because predicates in XPath filter the **context node list** you can't perform a join selection unless you are able to reintroduce target values from a relative context of your source values. Example selecting all the elements with the same name as that having specific `id` attribute:

```
//*[name()=name(//*[@id=$generated-id-string])]
```

Now, for the in *"between marks problem"* use as usually the Kaysian method for intersection:

```
//*[name()=name(//*[@id=$generated-id-string])]/preceding-sibling::node()[
   count(.|//*[@id=$generated-id-string]/following-sibling::node())
      =
   count(//*[@id=$generated-id-string]/following-sibling::node())
]
```

Test in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0dcfdf59dccb8faf3705c22167ae45f1

Comment: When I test your code against real data on your test platform I get the following error : `ERROR - Seem like XML is not well formed:The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.`

Comment: I tried it with scrapy I get all the text from the id to the end of the document maybe it's due to same fact mal formed xml

Comment: @Deyesta This works and there is the test case with your own input sample. If there is other input for wich this XPath expression doesn't select what you want, please be free to post your test case as I did.